# ng test --include for a specific file is still executing all spec files

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I've got an Angular 13 app and I'm running the following script to only execute one spec file, but it's still executing everything:

```
npx ng test --include src/app/services/mySharedService.spec.ts
```

my *test.ts* is standard and has this snippet:

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\ts$/);
```

my *karma.conf.js* is standard, too. with a basePath of ''.

Either way, the script I run should override all those and only execute the file I include. What am I doing wrong?

i checked the documentation and the *--include* option mentions an array as the value type. so i tried adding that via:

```
npx ng test --include ['src/app/services/mySharedService.spec.ts']
```

and it says that it did not match any spec files.

even this snippet will execute tests outside the *services* folder:

```
ng test --include='**/services/*.spec.ts'
```

Comment: I've had trouble with this before too.  My only solution was to add `f` to the beginning of the `it` test (so it reads `fit(...` or on the `describe` (so it reads `fdescribe(...`.

Comment: There are errors in many test files and I'm trying to execute just one file that has no errors instead of all those others. Seems like Angular wants to force me to fix those first.

Comment: I understand.  But I think that if you do as I suggested in my comment above, it will NOT run the other tests.

Comment: That does work. I've quickly commented out the errors in my other spec files and it's running fine now. Takeaway: all spec files must be clear of errors to even test just one.